# How to send a string or an array to laravel middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on Laravel and try to make an`ACL` system. I have a Role Middleware From myController I've sent `Role` to my RoleMiddleware two way.

first one is send string.

```
$this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author');
```

this way i'm get a string when use `dd()` function.

and the second way is.

```
$this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author');
```

this way i'm get an array when use `dd()` function.
but this array only contains a single value.

result like this.

`array:1 [▼
  0 => "User"
]`

other two value `Admin` & `Author` doesn't appear in this array.

**How can i work both way string & array**

Here is my middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next,$role='')
{


    $roles=is_array($role)? $role: explode('|', $role);
   dd($roles);

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: explode by `,` not by `|` when using `$this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author');`

Comment: `,` define for an array, so when given`$this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author')` is check on `is_array()` function

Comment: are you using `...$roles` as parameter ?

Comment: `...$roles` only work for `$this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author')` not `$this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author');`

Comment: see docs [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#middleware-parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#middleware-parameters)

Comment: then use `,` instead `|` whats wrong with this ?

Comment: @Majeed when i tested your code with `|` it is printing perfect array, you can use it

Answer (score 0):

I know maybe not exactly the answer to your question, but I recommend you to use laravel authorization instead middleware. [see this doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization)

I prefer to use this code for your problem in the controller:

```
$this->authorize('update', $post);
```

or:

```
if ($user->can('create', Post::class)) {
    // Executes the "create" method on the relevant policy...
}
```

then inside the policy file, you should specify the statement like:

```
if ($user->isSuperAdmin() || $user->id === $post->user_id) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want middleware to automatically convert your string to array then middleware `$role` params should be like this

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$roles)
{
   dd($roles);

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

Then use it like this `$this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author');`

**OR**

But if you want some other character to separate your roles like `|` then the code should be

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role = '')
{
   $roles = explode('|', $role);

   dd($roles);

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

And use it like `$this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use both, just add some code in your middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next,...$role)
{
  //add two line 

   $str_role=explode('|',$role[0]);
   $roleString=$str_role;

     $roles=is_array($role)? $role : is_array($roleString)? $roleString : null;
     //dd($roles);

    if($request->user()===null)
    {
        return response('Insufficient Access',401);
    }

    if($request->user()->hasAnyRole($roles) || !$roles)
    {
         return $next($request);
    }
      return response('Insufficient Permission',401);
    //return $next($request);
}
```

NOW, you can use.

> $this->middleware('HasRole:User|Admin|Author');

OR,

> $this->middleware('HasRole:User,Admin,Author');